# DJango api to send refresh and access tokens

Tags: django, frameworks

```
def login(request):

    username = request.data.get("username")
    password = request.data.get("password")
    if username is None or password is None:
        return Response({'error': 'Please provide both username and password'},
                        status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if not user:
        return Response({'error': 'Invalid Credentials'},
                        status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    return Response({'token': token.key},
                    status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Hi, How can i modify this code to send refresh token and access token for first time and send access token by receiving refresh token.
please help to do that.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible without destroying your previous generated token. If you want new authtoken every time you login here you can ensure first that you destroy the earlier token and create a new one.

```
 from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
 try:
     token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
     token.delete()
     token = Token.objects.create(user=user)

 except ObjectDoesNotExist:
     token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
```

Comment: sorry i don't get the difference between refresh and access token.  What do you mean by refresh token ?

Comment: hi Shakil, 
i've written the code for generating access token only. My question is hw can i send both refresh and access token.
in My api response i should be able to generate access token or refresh token based on the grant type
See the below:
...
grant_type=request.data.get('grant_type')
if(grant_type == 'password'):
    ... 
    # code to send both refresh token & access token
elif(grant_type =='refresh_token'):
    refresh_token = request.data.get('refresh_token');
     ...
     code to send access token for the given refresh token
I hope u understood. 
pls help to get thanks

Comment: are they same? refresh and access tokens?

Comment: sorry i misunderstood the question.